# Swift OSX - update NSTextView from another class and maybe thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, user-interface

I'm brand new to Swift programming and my background has always been procedural languages so am coming to terms with both the language and some OO concepts.

I'm building an OSX application that has 1 GUI window, with 2 input fields and a button - when the button is clicked, the program takes image files from the folder entered in 1 of the text boxes and copies them to the folder entered in the second text box. On this main window us a NSTextView that acts as an output log so the user knows the progress of the copies.

```
ViewController.swift 
utilities.swift
ImageCopy.swift
```

The 3 controls are defined in my ViewController

```
@IBOutlet var logView: NSTextView!
@IBOutlet weak var sourceFolder: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var targetFolder: NSTextField!
```

The button code is:

```
@IBAction func ExecuteButtonPressed(_ sender: NSButtonCell){
    utilities.writeToLog(lineOfText: "Copy process starting\n")
    processImages(inputFolder, outputFolder) // <-- This can take some time
utilities.writeToLog(lineOfText: "Copy process ended\n")
}
```

in utilities.swift the writeToLog function is defined as:

```
class utilities{
    static func writeToLog(lineOfText: String){

    // Get current viewcontroller where the logview textview is
    let vc = (NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.contentViewController as! ViewController)

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let time=calendar.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second], from: Date())

    let outputLineOfText = "\(time.hour!):\(time.minute!):\(time.second!) - " + lineOfText

    vc.logView.textStorage?.append(NSAttributedString(string: outputLineOfText))
    vc.logView.scrollToEndOfDocument(self)

}
```

All the copy functionality is in the ImageCopy.swift file and utilises the writeToLog() function to attempt to write to the GUI control as it progresses.

The application is all working with one exception - as the ProcessImages() function can take so long, and from what I can understand is running on the main thread, it blocks the GUI updates so once the ProcessImages() function returns the logView NSTextView updates all at once.

I think I need to run the ProcessImages() function on a thread, however when I did that it still didn't update the logView.

Any help would be much appreciated.

************************************** UPDATE

I think I'm on the right path now. I'm investigating delegates and Notifications to communicate between the background thread and the UI View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

************************************** UPDATE

I think I'm on the right path now. I'm investigating delegates and Notifications to communicate between the background thread and the UI View.

Comment: To make your own answer useful for other people questioning the same as you, you should expand it with examples or links to documentation. :)